# IIS URL Rewrite Module : Rewrite Query String Value using Map

Tags: iis, iis-7, url-rewriting

I would like to rewrite a query string value using a map in the IIS Url Rewrite Module.

Example Map:

```
one   -> eleven
two   -> fifty  
three -> ninety
```

So the following URL:

> `http://www.mydomain.com/page.aspx?id=one`

turns in to:

> `http://www.mydomain.com/page.aspx?id=eleven`

**Note:** there may be other query parameters passed in the URL which i do not want removed

Answer (score -1):

why not Url Mapping

```
<urlMappings enabled="true">
      <add url="~/page.aspx?id=one" mappedUrl="~/page.aspx?id=eleven"/>
</urlMappings>
```

Comment: marked down as this solution doesn't take into account that there could be additional querystring parameters passed in that the asker would not want removed.